# ¿Cómo ignorar un directorio completo, incluyendo todos sus directorios y archivos en un proyecto de Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, git

Tengo el siguiente directorio:

```
MiProyecto/app/src/main/assets/database
```

Y dentro de él tengo unos archivos de base de datos que no quiero incluir en el repositorio de Github. En definitiva, yo quiero ignorar todo el contenido de `assets/database` con `.gitignore`, pero no lo consigo.

He probado con cosas como:

```
assets/*/
assets/database
assets/database/
/assets/database/
```

en los archivos siguientes:

```
MiProyecto/.gitignore
```

Y:

```
MiProyecto/app/.gitignore
```

Pero no funciona, los archivos de `assets` no son ignorados. ¿Cómo podría lograrlo?

Answer (score 2):

Si ya los archivos fueron agregados previamente y son parte de la historia de la rama, el archivo `.gitignore` no tiene ningún efecto.

En general hay 2 formas de manejarlo:

Puedes borrar los archivos dejándolos en tu árbol de trabajo.

```
git rm --cached -r MiProyecto/app/src/main/assets/database
git commit -m "Borrando unos archivos que quiero ignorar"
```

Con eso los borras de esta revisión (y hacia adelante) y entonces el `.gitignore` si los tomaría en cuenta. Esto tiene la desventaja de que si haces un checkout de una revisión **con los archivos**, git se va a quejar.... *y* si luego regresas a una revisión que no los tiene, los archivos se van a borrar.

La otra forma es borrando los archivos de la historia, como si nunca los hubieras acometido. Esto tiene el inconveniente de que reescribe a historia de la (o las) rama (o ramas). Si los archivos los agregaste en la revision X, por ejemplo., podrías hacer esto:

```
git rebase -i X~ # usar el rabo de cochino en la revisión
# la revisión X debería ser la primera de la lista
# le colocas edit como acción, guardas y sales
# el rebase va a ejecutar y se va a detener justo luego de aplicar
# la revisión en la que los archivos fueron agregados
git rm --cached -r MiProyecto/app/src/main/assets/database
# agrega tambien el item al .gitignore
git add .gitignore
# enmendamos la revisión
git commit --amend --no-edit
# dejamos que el rebase termine de correr
git rebase --continue
```

Y ya! Es como si los archivos nunca los hubieras agregado al proyecto (y están ignorados). Si es algo más complejo, tendrías que considerar usar `git filter-repo` https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Se trata de unos archivos de base de datos (por el momento incompletos) pero que no me interesa estén en el repositorio, el que hayan estado no me importa, pero no quiero seguir subiéndoles ni quiero que estén cuando el proyecto esté en su fase definitiva. ¿Es mejor en ese caso aplicar la primera sugerencia de tu respuesta? No entendí bien lo que significa esto: *si haces un checkout de una revisión con los archivos, git se va a quejar....* No soy muy experto en git.

Comment: Si el proyecto es propio y tu eres el único que lo está usando en este momento, lo mejor es reescribir la historia para que los archivos nunca se vean en la historia de la rama. La reescritura de historia no se recomienda en caso de ramas compartidas.

Comment: Sí, es un proyecto propio y no hay más colaboradores.

Comment: Para explicar lo de la queja de git sobre la que preguntas. Supón que haces la primera sugerencia. Los borras (con `--cached`) hoy y acometes.... y trabajas varios días más sin problemas. Luego digamos que quieres hacer checkout de una revisión de _ayer_ (que contiene los archivos). En ese caso git se quejaría porque la revisión pide colocar en el árbol de trabajo unos archivos que ya tu tienes en el árbol de trabajo... digamos que le haces un `git checkout -f` para obligarlo a hacer checkout de la revisión de ayer. Bien.... continúo en otro mensaje.

Comment: Luego de que haces lo que requieres, probablemente quieras regresar a la punta de la rama. En ese punto haces `git checkout la-rama` y entonces git va a ir a esa revisión _y_ va a borrar los archivos de tu árbol de trabajo (porque estaban en la revisión donde estabas parado.... y no están en la revisión a la que te estás moviendo).

Comment: Ok, entendí ese punto, entonces, si he entendido todo correctamente, es mejor aplicar la segunda opción que propones, dejando todo limpio, como si esos archivos nunca hubieran existido... Mi duda en ese punto es sobre esto: `git rebase -i X~` ¿qué debo poner ahí, el valor de la primera revisión en la que agregué esos archivos, o el valor de la última revisión? Una vez subí unos archivos con datos sensibles y recuerdo estar viendo algo sobre `git-filter-repo` pero no pude con ello y pedí al personal de Github que borrasen esos archivos, cosa que hicieron.

Comment: La primera revisión en la que los agregaste.

Comment: Como te decía, en casos sencillos, un `git rebase -i` puede hacer el trabajo. Si es algo más complejo, un `git filter-repo` podría ser lo que necesites.

Comment: Volveré a ver lo de [`git filter-repo`](https://docs.github.com/es/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository), me parece la mejor opción, aunque como dije, aquella vez o no lo entendí o no pude lograrlo por algún motivo, pero me parece la solución más idónea.